# How to scrape Source View of a Page?

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to scrape a page by its sourceview.
For example:
view-source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3-zAlsCJ4c&t=1607s

I can not get it by this code:

```
res = requests.get('view-source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3-zAlsCJ4c&t=1607s')
```

It causes an error like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:\Users\hdtra\Desktop\In processing\Facebook_spider.py", line 31, in <module>
>   res = requests.get('view-source:https://www.facebook.com/pg/vuonraunhatrang/about/?ref=page_internal')
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
>   return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
>   return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
>   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 612, in send
>   adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in get_adapter
>   raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
> requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'view-source:https://www.facebook.com/pg/vuonraunhatrang/about/?ref=page_internal'
> ```

How I can scrape this Viewsource link?

A scrape using `.get()` method does not work on my project.

I don't have enough information from that normal page, but with this viewsource windows, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib 

r =urllib.urlopen(<url_to_scrape>).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r) 
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Sorry but it Still not Work. urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: view-source>

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, I got error `ImportError: No module named bs4`

Comment: It should go without saying that you have to install bs4 first

Comment: I Install already, but it mean that Python can not understand my link which start with Viewsource:...